# Disable jquery validation for a particular field

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, livevalidation

I am using jQuery live validation for twitter bootstrap(https://github.com/ddarren/jQuery-Live-Form-Validation-For-Twitter-Bootstrap) in my rails app.I want to remove the validation from a field for a particular condition.
Ex:

```
if(project=='Fixed'){
 $("#project_price").validate({
     expression: "if(VAL != '') return true; else return false;",
     message: "Price  is required."
  });
}
else{
//Disable validation for price field
}
```

Can anyone suggest how to remove/disable jQuery live validation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just to overwrite the behaviour with something like:

```
$("#project_price").validate({
     expression: "return true;",
});
```

?